# js получить внутренности

Tags: javascript

Есть подключенная страница `<script src="http://site.com/php"></script>`. В ней есть js и html код.

Задача такая:

- Как-то достать содержимое src скрипта, то есть полностью его код;
- Либо отключить чтение html символов, но заставить выполнять js
  который в тэге `<script>` на странице.

Проблема - нет доступа к источнику.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Политика кроссдоменности не позволит. А если бы позволяла, можно было бы ajax-запросом получить страницу.

Кстати, можно на своём сервере настроить хендлер, который будет запрашивать ту страницу и пересылать её сайту.

Ну или сразу скрипты один раз достать и их и подключать, а не страницу.